# UWP App Icon in taskbar is not displaying properly

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, uwp

When I run my app in the image which I displayed is visible but around that white background is also showing. How to remove that one. 
does Any one have idea about this? [image]

Comment: Upload your icon file somewhere and post the link

Comment: You need to open your image in something like Paint.net http://www.getpaint.net/index.html , cut the white out and save it as a png.

Comment: while I am uploading the white color is not there..      http://www.technolabssoftware.com/   here  is the logo

Comment: What are you using to create your icon?

Comment: You don't see the white colour because the It is a Layer of actual Image. See my answer.

Comment: Please make sure the icon you've used is a png image with transparent background. For details, please check [Target-based assets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-app-assets#Target-based_assets).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your image a vector. Microsoft provides Expression Design to do this.

[Here is a Quick Video on how to vectorize an Bitmap Image to Vector Image](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/expression/cc482959.aspx)

If you do not Have Expression Design Installed already. [Click Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36180)

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I have given 24x24 image at wrong place. It should be at **Unplated Target size 24** so that I got the right image.